# Passing Facebook access token to comments plugin from native app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-access-token

We are developing a mobile app (Android and iOS) which embeds an HTML page to display articles. We added the Facebook JS SDK to the page but it does not seem to allow to set an access token, unlike its native counterpart.

The user is already logged in to Facebook within our app using native SDK and we have the access token. How can we pass this access token to the HTML page so that he's also logged in in the page? Both the HTML page and native app share the same app ID.

I tried appending `?access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to the URL with no success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ever? i mean you got the solution?